# Responsive form how to make the textbox expand?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div that contains a label followed by input tag. I want the label to be a constant width, whereas the textbox would expand to whatever is left over in its parent.

```
<div class="user">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="USER" id="username">
</div>
```

Currently I float both controls to the left.

```
.user label, .user input {
   float: left;
}
```

If I set label width to 150px, how can I get the textbox to take the remaining space but not drop on to another line? I tried width 'auto' and it didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: try `width:100%` for textbox.

Comment: this was pushing on to the next line. Likely a side effect of some surrounding css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, using CSS `calc()`. I skipped the `float` as it is not needed, but you can use it if you want.

To be noted, `calc()` has slightly better browser support than `flex` and keep your CSS rule cleaner.

```css
.user label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
.user input {
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="USER" id="username">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Using **CSS3 flexbox**.

```css
.user {
  display: flex;
}
.user label {
  width: 150px;
  background: pink;
}
.user input {
  flex: 1; /*expand*/
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="USER" id="username">
</div>
```

2. Using **CSS table** (additional markup).

```css
.user {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.user span {
  display: table-cell;
}
.user span:first-child {
  width: 150px;
  background: pink;
}
.user input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
  <span><label for="username">Username</label></span>
  <span><input type="text" name="USER" id="username"></span>
</div>
```

3. Using **calc() + float**.

```css
.user:after {
  /*clear float - may not necessary in this case as 100% width*/
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.user label {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  background: pink;
}
.user input {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="USER" id="username">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best done with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
    .user {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
    .user label{
        width: 150px;
    }

    .user input {
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-self:  flex-end;
    }
```